# Provide user to be able to choose files from his Box using my website

Tags: box-api, box

Is there in the Box API some kind of dropbox alike chooser, to provide functionality to choose user's content from his Box, and response via API to our backend/frontend the file data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this quite easily with the Box File-picker:

```
<div id="box-select" data-link-type="YOUR_LINK_TYPE" data-multiselect="YOUR_MULTISELECT" data-client-id="YOUR_CLIENT_ID"></div>
```

Full details here:

https://developers.box.com/the-box-file-picker/